# How to center a dialog window on the main window in GTK?

Tags: c, gtk

I want to print small warning messages. To achieve that, I'm creating a new window and I want it to be centered on the main window. So far I've tried setting its parent with `gtk_widget_set_parent`, using `GTK_WINDOW_POPUP` and `GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL` but nothing worked.

**How to center the window on the main window?**

Here's the code for the function:

```
static void pop_warning(char *title, char *text)
{
    GtkWidget *warning_window;
    GtkWidget *box;
    GtkWidget *label;
    GtkWidget *button;

    warning_window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(warning_window), title);
    g_signal_connect(GTK_WINDOW(warning_window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_widget_destroy), NULL);
    gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(warning_window), 20);
    gtk_window_set_resizable(GTK_WINDOW(warning_window), FALSE);    

    //window is the main window
    gtk_widget_set_parent(warning_window, window);
    gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(warning_window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER_ON_PARENT);

    box = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 10);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(warning_window), box);

    label = gtk_label_new(text);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box), label, TRUE, FALSE, 0);

    button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Ok");
    g_signal_connect_swapped(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(gtk_widget_destroy), warning_window);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box), button, TRUE, FALSE, 0);

    gtk_widget_show_all(warning_window);    
}
```

Comment: Can you add a screenshot... and what window manager do you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(warning_window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER_ON_PARENT);
```

only works if you first call

```
gtk_window_set_transient_for(GtkWindow *window, GtkWindow *parent);
```

as mentioned explicitly in the documentation.

You could also try to use `GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER_ALWAYS` that has not the above mentioned constrain - at least not according the docs.

Comment: I didn't know a dialog did the same thing implicitly, so I removed my answer.